# compare and count from two tables using laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

```
id  sm_id  to_id
1   3      2
2   4      1
3   3      3
4   3      2
5   3      3
6   4      1
```

How can I count how many occurences of a `to_id` an `sm_id` has?

I have two inputs, first `sm_id` and second `to_id`, I want to count occurence of values based on inputs.

Expected result for `sm_id = 4 and to_id = 1` would be `2`

Here's the code I tried

```
$us = \DB::table('mgs')
                 ->where('sm_id', '=', DB::raw('to_id'))
        ->where('to_id', '=', DB::raw('sm_id'))
                 ->groupBy('sm_id')
                 ->count();

      print_r($us);die;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to count how many messages with given `sm_id` and `to_id` in the table, do this:

```
\DB::table('msg')->where('sm_id', $smId)->where('to_id', $toId)->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$us = \DB::table('mgs')
            ->where('sm_id', '=', DB::raw('to_id'))
            ->where('to_id', '=', DB::raw('sm_id'))
            ->groupBy('sm_id', 'to_id')
            ->count('sm_id', 'to_id');

print_r($us);die;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have `$sm_id` and `$to_id` as an input then you dont need to use `DB::raw` as you are using `Laravel query builder` so it will take care of **SQL injection**:

```
$us = \DB::table('mgs')->where(['sm_id'=>$sm_id,'to_id'=>$to_id])->count();
dd($us);
```

`dd()` is method of laravel which stands for **dump and die** so you dont need to use `print_r` and `die` separately.

PS. I have used `\DB` from your script but I advise to use: `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB` instead.